# Summing values in separate workbook using two matching values from current worksheet

Tags: excel, time, sum, criteria

[ADDED the read of the tab name which is the project number in Cell G1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLMgU.png)I have a database dump in one workbook.
I have set-up a separate workbook with multiple worksheets where the tabs are named with a project number.
I have a list of names in cells A7:A13 and need time totals in F7:F13.
The database dump work sheet has names in the A column, Project number in D column and Hours in F column.
I need the formula in F7 to use the corresponding name in A7 and the project number from the tab name to sum up all the time in the database dump workbook on rows with matching name and project number and return the total to A7.
Then do the same for all other names.

Here is a typical worksheet where I need the time sums for each name:
[image]

Database Dump typical row:
[image]

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

UPDATE 1:  I think I have a viable solution.  The SUMIFS(...) formula:  I tried the following first attempt and it did not work (returned a zero) but I believe this is the most elegant solution:
=SUMIFS('Report-TimeSheetEntry.xls'!$F$4:$F$50000,'Report-TimeSheetEntry.xls'!$A$4:$A$50000,A7='Report-TimeSheetEntry.xls'!$A$4,'Report-TimeSheetEntry.xls'!$D$4:$D$50000, $G$1='Report-TimeSheetEntry.xls'!$D$4)

UPDATE 2 and solved (works perfectly) still work to do. the range can't extend past the last row of data or else you get #Value:
=SUMIFS('Report-TimeSheetEntry.xls'!$F$4:$F$41695,'Report-TimeSheetEntry.xls'!$A$4:$A$41695,A7,'Report-TimeSheetEntry.xls'!$D$4:$D$41695,$G$1)

Comment: Your explanation is reasonably clear, but it would help even more if you could add to your post a sample of the data and a sample of the results you're looking for. Using that, also post what you've already tried as a forumla.

Comment: Thanks Peter.  I added screenshots of showing the typical worksheet tab and the typical database dump row.

Comment: I am not sure the best way to approach this.  Is there an existing function?  I was looking at a macro but it adds over a specific range of cells and does not need to filter using the two criteria.

Comment: If your database dump worksheet is named `Dump` (for example), you can try (in cell F7 on 26055 sheet) the formula `=SUMIF(Dump!$A:$A,A7,Dump!$F:$F)`.

Comment: Thanks PeterT.  I like how simple that is.  Excel amazes me.  SUMIF only allows for one criteria.  That's why I am using the SUMIFS function: I need it to search and sum values in the time column that match the tab name (project number which I have now showing up in cell G1 using a formula that reads the tab name) AND the person's name from the A column.